# How to prepend to a file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, prepend, powershell-core

I'm generating two files, `userscript.meta.js` and `userscript.user.js`. I need the output of `userscript.meta.js` to be placed at the very beginning of `userscript.user.js`.

`Add-Content` doesn't seem to accept a parameter to prepend and `Get-Content | Set-Content` will fail because `userscript.user.js` is being used by `Get-Content`.

I'd rather not create an intermediate file if it's physically possible to have a clean solution.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I agree with not wanting an intermediate file 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) can evaluate both [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2) statements which are then enumerated and passed through the pipeline to [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
$(
    Get-Content userscript.meta.js -Raw
    Get-Content userscript.user.js -Raw
) | Set-Content userscript.user.js
```

Consider using the **Absolute Path** of the files if your current directory is not where those files are.

---

An even more simplified approach than the above would be to put the paths in the desired order since both, the [`-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#-path) and [`-LiteralPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#-literalpath) parameters can take multiple values:

```bash
(Get-Content userscript.meta.js, userscript.user.js -Raw) |
    Set-Content userscript.user.js
```

And in case you want to get rid of excess leading or trailing white-space, you can include the [`String.Trim` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0#system-string-trim):

```bash
(Get-Content userscript.meta.js, userscript.user.js -Raw).Trim() |
    Set-Content userscript.user.js
```

Note that in above examples the [grouping operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) is mandatory as we need to consume all output from `Get-Content` **before** being passed through the pipeline to `Set-Content`. See [**Piping grouped expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#piping-grouped-expressions) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

For future folks, here's a snippet **if you need to prepend the same thing to multiple files**:

example: prepending an `#include` directive to a bunch of auto-generated C++ files so it works with my Windows environment.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.cpp | ForEach-Object { 
    $file = $_.FullName

    # the -Raw param was important for me as it didn't read the entire
    # file properly without it. I even tried [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText
    # and got the same thing, so there must have been some characater that
    # caused the file read to return prematurely
    $content = Get-Content $file -Raw

    $prepend = '#include "stdafx.h"' + "`r`n"
    #this could also be from a file: aka
    # $prepend = Get-Content 'path_to_my_file_used_for_prepending'
    
    $content =  $prepend + $content
    Set-Content $file $content
}
```

Comment: I feel like this should be in its own question