# Powershell Prepend Header File to Huge Non-csv Data File Without Creating 3rd File

Tags: powershell, header, prepend

I have a 2GB pipe-delimited data file. I would like to use PowerShell to prepend a header to the file without creating a third file. Looking at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749929/how-do-i-concatenate-two-text-files-in-powershell), I would like to change

```
Get-Content inputFile1.txt, inputFile2.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

to

```
Get-Content inputFile1.txt, inputFile2.txt | Set-Content inputFile2.txt
```

without creating a third file. What's the best way?

I see that it seems simple to capture data from many files into a **new** one. Is there a efficient way to combine files in some other way - perhaps by editing the text of the large file instead?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852305/how-to-prepend-to-a-file-in-powershell/67852426#67852426

Comment: if you need to preserve memory / need to stream data to the output file then there is another way around __but you must have at least `inputFile2.txt` in memory__

Comment: You could read only one file content (however order/sequence matters) as follows: `Get-Content inputFile2.txt | Out-File inputFile1.txt -APPEND`